# Camel Spring EMS SSL not working

Tags: spring, ssl, apache-camel

We have used Camel for routing between different destination using Spring with EMS messaging:

EMS Queues/TOpics hosted on tcp/http protocol working fine, whereease SSL causes following exception:

```
Error: Error occured while reading identity data: failed to decrypt safe contents entry: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded: url that returned this exceptio= ssl://random.host.com:41943
```

For normal spring tibco EMS SSL connection we need to set following by overriding ListenerContainer:

```
TibjmsSSL.setPassword(passwordCharArray);
```

How can we do with camel configuration:

```
<bean id="jmsConfig" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="userCredentialsConnectionFactory" />
        <property name="transacted" value="false" />
        <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="1" />
        </property>
    </bean>
```

This is my camel jms config

I tried overriding following with my own custom implementation by setting below property, it doesnt seem to override required functionality:

```
org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration.messageListenerContainerFactory
```

Answer (score 0):

[Fixed]

Overrided `doCreateConnection(String,String)` method of import `org.springframework.jms.connection.UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter`

and set required password in `TibjmsSSL.setPassword(passwordCharArray)`